# Getting unexpected results when refining DOM selection

Tags: jquery, node.js, jsdom

I have this very weird behavior that when I try to get the text of certain `div` elements, I get all previous "matches" when chaining multiple jQuery functions.

This is my code:

```
var rows = $("tr");
    var groups = [];
    for (var i = 0;i<rows.length;i++){
        if(rows.eq(i).html().toString().match(/TV/i)){
            groups += rows.eq(i).find(":first-child div").text();
        }
    }
    console.log(groups);
```

Now the output that I expect is just the text contained in the div that is contained in the first child of the matched table-row.
I do get that result in the console but before that I get the text of all `tr`'s, all matched `tr`'s (`.eq(i)`), all td's (`:first-child` is a `td`), all `div`s and THEN at the last bit of the output I get the text that is contained in the first `div`.

So `groups` is holding all things like I would have done something like this:

```
groups += rows.eq(i)
groups += rows.eq(i).find(":first-child")
groups += rows.eq(i).find("div")
groups += rows.eq(i).find("div").text();
```

I'm fairly new to jQuery and only used standard JavaScript selectors where `getElementById("myID").getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML`, would give me just the `innerHTML` of the first `div` in `myID` and nothing else.

Why is this happening and how can I get what I'm actually looking for?

Comment: First : Is it possible to have a fiddle of your problem? Second : If groups is an array, it should be `groups.push(value)` instead of `groups += value`

Comment: Its running in node.js as mentioned in the tag so a fiddle is sadly not possible.
True about the .push. I did not declared it as a array before and left the +=. Though I still get the same weird results.

Comment: It is not possible to have the HTML output with node.js, like the source code in the browser? (I never used node.js yet)

Comment: What exactly do you mean with HTML output?
I do get my output with console.log() right now.
Posting that output would be rather painfull though, its a few thousand lines.

Comment: I edited the question. Maybe its more clear now what my problem is.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but is node.js creating an HTML page? If yes, having a fiddle with the page source code (right click -> source code) would be very helpfull. If no, then you cant, infact, create a fiddle.

Comment: oh no, its server side JS but not like PHP. This is has no visual output. Normally node doesn't even have DOM thats why I'm using domjs. I'm crawling for information on a website that contains the word "TV". I do get that information but I also get a bunch of other information that I have no idea why its even there.

Answer (score 1):

After exploring your code, I think I finaly found you probleme. IT's hard to tell since we cant see the DOM output.

Anyway, using `.find(':first-child div')` will get every first-child inside the tr.

Example :

```
td
-tr <-- Is :first-child (of td)
--div <-- is also :first-child and :first-child div (will get the text of this div)
---div <-- is also :first-child and :first-child div (will get the text of this div)
-tr
--div Is :first-child (of tr)
---div <-- is also :first-child and :first-child div (will get the text of this div)
```

Try using this instead :

```
groups.push(rows.eq(i).children(":first-child").find('div').text());
```

Hope it help (and actually was your problem)!

Comment: sadly still the same weird issue :/ but an upvote for you, it was helpfull either way.
Posting any output is hard as its really long and contains personal info, I hesitate posting that.
I resolved my issue for now by just deleting the firs 2 entries of my array for everytime the loop runs. Those contain the text of firstly all the divs within td's on the site, then those results in the format of one big string and then my desired filtered results of only the text of the matching elements.

Comment: Your issue is really wierd ahah, as long as you have a fix, it's ok! But your code is "working" so it is probably a DOM issue...

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can cycle for you...

```
$.each($("tr"), function($index, jsObj)
{
    $jQueryObj = $(jsObj);
    /* ... */
});
```

alternative usage of .each:

```
$("tr").each(function($index, jsObj)
{
    /* etc */
});
```

also I *believe* there was a functionality like `.has(":content('TV')")`, but I'm not 100% sure on that at the moment.

Comment: Just to clarify, `$.each(arg,func())` is for when you have a none jQuery array object. Doing `$.each($("tr")...)` call twice `$` (wich is bad). Also (just to point it out), `jsObj` can be accessed with `this`, but this way our your way is the same, just a personnal preference.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I ran into some problems with ajax json data when using `this` in an `.each` function while the method above worked fine in all scenarios. In order to avoid using both methods mixed (readability etc), I've decided to simply go ahead with `...(index, obj)` as it simply does not cause me these problems. (Encountered using jQuery 1.9.1, not sure if that's a bug)

Comment: there is the .content() function but its case sensitive and I need case insensitive matching.
Also I'm not quite sure how this helping with my issue, isn't this just an alternative for the for loop?